# Prove that $m + n$ is even if and only if $m^{5} - n^{5}$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried doing a direct proof and a proof by contradiction and manipulating the $m^{5} - n^{5}$ expression but I didn't really reach any meaningful end. It's an exercise (not homework) problem.

Comment: Hint: $m$ is even iff $m^5$ is even.

Comment: You can always brute force four cases: m even n even, m even n odd, m odd n even, m odd n odd

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $m^5-n^5=(m+n)(m^4-m^3n+m^2n^2-mn^3+n^4)$. Now if $m+n$ is even then $m^5-n^5$ is also even. If $m+n$ odd, then either "$m$ is even and $n$ is odd" or "$m$ is odd and $n$ is even". Assume that $m$ is even and $n$ is odd, then since $m$ is even we have $m^4-m^3n+m^2n^2-mn^3=m(m^3-m^2n+mn^2-n^3)$ is also even, and $n^4 $ is odd. Hence,  $m^4-m^3n+m^2n^2-mn^3+n^4$ is odd and so $m+n$ and $m^4-m^3n+m^2n^2-mn^3+n^4$ are odd. Thus, $m^5-n^5=(m+n)(m^4-m^3n+m^2n^2-mn^3+n^4)$ is odd. Similar argument works for the case "$m$ is odd and $n$ is even". Therefore, $m + n$ is even if and only if $m^{5} - n^{5}$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how this translates into modular arithmetic and you understand how modular arithmetic works, you can do this:

"$x$ is even" is equivalent to $x\equiv 0 \pmod2,$
and "$x$ is odd" is equivalent to $x\equiv 1 \pmod2.$
So you have to show that $m + n \equiv m^5 - n^5 \pmod2.$

But $x^5 \equiv x \pmod 2$ for any integer $x$
(because $0^5 \equiv 0 \pmod2$ and $1^5 \equiv 1 \pmod2$)
and $-y \equiv y \pmod2$  for any integer $y$
(because $0 \equiv 0 \pmod2$ and $-1 \equiv 1 \pmod2$),
so $$m^5 - n^5 \equiv m - n \equiv m + n \pmod2,$$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

By considering all the three cases, we have

- $m,n$ even $\implies m + n$ even and $m^5-n^5$ even
- $m,n$ odd $\implies m + n$ even and $m^5-n^5$ even
- $m,n$ odd and even $\implies m + n$ odd and $m^5-n^5$ odd